# ExecutionError: Exceeded the prepaid gas -- when called from front end

Tags: nearprotocol

The `transfer()` function works perfectly fine when testing and through the CLI. However, when I try to call it from the front end, it returns

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Exceeded the prepaid gas."}}

It is not a complex call and only involves just 1. transferring tokens 2. updating a value in storage. Can anyone give me pointers as to why this might be happening?

```js
document.querySelector('#transfer-to-owner').onclick = () => {
    console.log("Transfer about to begin")
    
    try {
         window.contract.transfer({})
     } catch (e) {
         'Something went wrong! ' +
         'Check your browser console for more info.'
     } 
}
```

contract from [this repo](https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/sample--thanks/tree/main/src/thanks)

```js
  const XCC_GAS: Gas = 20_000_000_000_000;

  transfer(): void {
    this.assert_owner()

    assert(this.contributions.received > u128.Zero, "No received (pending) funds to be transferred")

    const to_self = Context.contractName
    const to_owner = ContractPromiseBatch.create(this.owner)

    // transfer earnings to owner then confirm transfer complete
    const promise = to_owner.transfer(this.contributions.received)
    promise.then(to_self).function_call("on_transfer_complete", '{}', u128.Zero, XCC_GAS)
  }

  @mutateState()
  on_transfer_complete(): void {
    assert_self()
    assert_single_promise_success()

    logging.log("transfer complete")
    // reset contribution tracker
    this.contributions.record_transfer()
  }
```

Comment: How much gas did you attach to the call?

Comment: Doesn't gas get automatically attached from the function callers accounts in situations like this (https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/gas#how-do-i-buy-gas)? I've been calling this function through the CLI with "near call $CONTRACT transfer --account_id $OWNER
". 

Seems like I might have a misunderstanding of how gas is being dealt with in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`near-api-js` and `near-shell` use a different default value for gas.

[`near-api-js`](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/336bdf51311b75d86f5080d7918848ae7d774b72/src/account.ts#L35):

```
const DEFAULT_FUNC_CALL_GAS = new BN('30_000_000_000_000');
```

[`near-shell`](https://github.com/near/near-cli/blob/21893e69bc4282b92892e40a814242738b37abd1/commands/call.js#L14):

```js
        .option('gas', {
            desc: 'Max amount of gas this call can use (in gas units)',
            type: 'string',
            default: '100_000_000_000_000'
        })
```

I added `_`s to make it clearer that near-shell uses more than 3 times the amount of gas by default.